# how to rewrite the url in php with dynamic names based on id in the url

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

how To make url for as seo friendly.
Now the link is like 
http://www.example.com/memorial.php?id=354

We want it to be http://www.example.com/firstname-middlename-lastname

so here first,last,and middle names from db based on id.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please add your table schema. You have to add slug in your table.

Answer (score 0):

You can select  details from Db then 
You can use header("Location: http://www.example.com/firstname-middlename-lastname"); /* Redirect browser */
to redirect

Answer (score 0):

Approach to work with this -

1. Add the slug coloumn in your table
2. Give option to add slug to user or create slug dynamically and insert it into the table.
3. Write the ReWriteRule to understand the request

**Example:-** Is given to add dynamic slug.

1.User Table Schema is like -

```
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| user_id        | int(11)             | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| first_name     | varchar(255)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| middle_name    | varchar(255)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name      | varchar(255)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| slug           | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

2. Before inserting user information into the User table use regular expression to support dnyamic seo slug-

   ```
   function seo_str_replace($str){
           $str = preg_replace("/^[^a-z0-9]+/", "", $str);
           $str = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9]+$/", "", $str);
           $str = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9]/", "-", $str);
           return $str;
   }

   $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
   $middle_name = $_POST['middle_name'];
   $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];

   $slugArr = Array();          

   if(!empty($first_name)){
      $slugArr[] = $first_name;
   }


   if(!empty($middle_name)){
      $slugArr[] = $middle_name;
   }


   if(!empty($last_name)){
      $slugArr[] = $last_name;
   }
   $slug = seo_str_replace(implode('-',$slugArr);
   ```
3. Insert slug into the table "User"

   ```
   $sql = "insert into user(first_name,middle_name,last_name,slug)values('$first_name','$middle_name','$last_name','$slug')";
   ```
4. To get the slug you have to use rewrite rule for url  **http://www.example.com/memorial/firstname-middlename-lastname** -

   ```
   RewriteRule ^/memorial/(.*)$ /memorial.php?slug=$1
   ```
5. On memorial.php get the slug & search it into the table.

   ```
    $slug = $_GET['slug'];
    $sql= "select user_id from User where slug = '".$slug."'";

    <!---- here Start your code --->
   ```

**Note:** Don’t forgot to add index on slug column.